# Create Numpy array without enumerating array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Starting with this:

```
x = range(30,60,2)[::-1];
x = np.asarray(x); x

array([58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30])
```

Create  an array like this: (Notice, first item repeats) But if I can get this faster without the first item repeating, I can `np.hstack` first item.

```
[[58 58 56 54 52]
 [56 56 54 52 50]
 [54 54 52 50 48]
 [52 52 50 48 46]
 [50 50 48 46 44]
 [48 48 46 44 42]
 [46 46 44 42 40]
 [44 44 42 40 38]
 [42 42 40 38 36]
 [40 40 38 36 34]
 [38 38 36 34 32]
 [36 36 34 32 30]
 [34 34 32 30 None]
 [32 32 30 None None]
 [30 30 None None None]]
```

The code below works, want it faster without 'for'  loop and enumerate.

```
arr = np.empty((0,5), int)

for i,e in enumerate(x):
    arr2 = np.hstack((x[i], x[i:i+4], np.asarray([None]*5)))[:5]
    arr  = np.vstack((arr,arr2))
```

Comment: for speed, I would get rid of `np._stack()` as it requires building a whole new object each time. Also if you could represent `None` as a numeric type: inf maybe.. you could avoid the slowdown of `dtype=object`

Comment: Right, if you can live with floats I would just go with that because because you can use NaN.

Comment: The None is a  database issue.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. You can use something like -1 or intmin for integer types. Just as long as the marker is unambiguously defined.

Comment: You can make `x` with `x=np.arange(58,28,-2)`

Comment: I wonder if there is some way of making the base matrix with `np.dot` and then putting in the `None` values after?

Comment: So, are you okay with a float array of NaNs as the last elements instead of `None`? If so, I would think the solutions would be more efficient as they would be indexing into a float array instead of an Obj array as the latter would be slower I think.

Comment: Removing None is ok, replacing with -99999, then using np.where to insert None  works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
N = 4 # width factor
x_ext = np.concatenate((x,[None]*(N-1)))
arr2D = x_ext[np.arange(N) + np.arange(x_ext.size-N+1)[:,None]]
out = np.column_stack((x,arr2D))
```

---

**Approach #2**

Here's another one using [`hankel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html) -

```
from scipy.linalg import hankel

N = 4 # width factor
x_ext = np.concatenate((x,[None]*(N-1)))
out = np.column_stack((x,hankel(x_ext[:4], x_ext[3:]).T))
```

---

**Runtime test**

Here's a modified version of [`@Aaron's benchmarking script`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024845/3293881) using an input format for this post identical to the one used for his post in that script for a fair benchmarking and focusing just on these two approaches -

```
upper_limit = 58 # We will edit this to vary the dataset sizes

print "Timings are : "
t = time()
for _ in range(1000):  #1000 iterations of @Aaron's soln.
    width = 3
    x = np.array(range(upper_limit,28,-2) + [float('nan')]*width)
    arr = np.empty([len(x)-width, width+2])
    arr[:,0] = x[:len(x)-width]
    for i in xrange(len(x)-width): 
        arr[i,1:] = x[i:i+width+1]
print(time()-t)

t = time()
for _ in range(1000): 
    N = 4 # width factor
    x_ext = np.array(range(upper_limit,28,-2) + [float('nan')]*(N-1))
    arr2D = x_ext[np.arange(N) + np.arange(x_ext.size-N+1)[:,None]]
    out = np.column_stack((x_ext[:len(x_ext)-N+1],arr2D))
print(time()-t)
```

Case #1 (upper_limit = 58 ) :

```
Timings are : 
0.0316879749298
0.0322730541229
```

Case #2 (upper_limit = 1058 ) :

```
Timings are : 
0.680443048477
0.124517917633
```

Case #3 (upper_limit = 5058 ) :

```
Timings are : 
3.28129291534
0.47504901886
```

Comment: So nice to scroll through all the ridiculous Python `for` loops and see a 4 line answer. Well, you are not at the bottom any more...

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've become obsessed with speed xP, but really, my original post was only 6 lines

Comment: With a little stride trickery we can write: `arr2D=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x_ext,shape=(15,4),strides=(4,4))`

Comment: @hpaulj Nice! You should port that as an answer!

Comment: @hpaulj, can you post as complete answer. would like to see it. Asked divakar about strides, yesterday.

Comment: @Merlin Added timings for bigger datasets, check it out!

Answer (score 3):

I got about an order of magnitude faster by avoiding `_stack()` and only using floats...

edit: added @Divakar's post to time trial...

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

t = time()
for _ in range(1000):  #1000 iterations of my soln.
    width = 3
    x = np.array(range(58,28,-2) + [float('nan')]*width)
    arr = np.empty([len(x)-width, width+2])
    arr[:,0] = x[:len(x)-width]
    for i in xrange(len(x)-width): 
        arr[i,1:] = x[i:i+width+1]
print(time()-t)

t = time()
for _ in range(1000):  #1000 iterations of OP code
    x = range(30,60,2)[::-1];
    x = np.asarray(x)
    arr = np.empty((0,5), int)
    for i,e in enumerate(x):
        arr2 = np.hstack((x[i], x[i:i+4], np.asarray([None]*5)))[:5]
        arr  = np.vstack((arr,arr2))
print(time()-t)

t = time()
for _ in range(1000): 
    x = np.array(range(58,28,-2))
    N = 4 # width factor
    x_ext = np.hstack((x,[None]*(N-1)))
    arr2D = x_ext[np.arange(N) + np.arange(x_ext.size-N+1)[:,None]]
    out = np.column_stack((x,arr2D))
print(time()-t)
```

prints out:

```
>>> runfile('...temp.py', wdir='...')
0.0160000324249
0.374000072479
0.0319998264313
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Divaker's padded `x`

```
N = 4 # width factor
x_ext = np.concatenate((x,[None]*(N-1)))
```

Since we aren't doing math on it, padding with None (which makes an object array) or `np.nan` (which makes a float) shouldn't make much difference.

The column stack could be eliminated with a little change to the indexing:

```
idx = np.r_[0,np.arange(N)] + np.arange(x_ext.size-N+1)[:,None]
```

this produces

```
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 3,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 4,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       ...
```

so the full result is

```
x_ext[idx]
```

================

A different approach is to use striding to create a kind of rolling window.

```
as_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
arr2D = as_strided(x_ext, shape=(15,4), str‌​ides=(4,4))
```

This is one of easier applications of `as_strided`.  `shape` is straight forward - the shape of the desired result (without the repeat column) `(x.shape[0],N)`.

```
In [177]: x_ext.strides
Out[177]: (4,)
```

For 1d array of this type, the step to the next item is 4 bytes.  If I reshape the array to 2d with 3 columns, the stride to the next row is 12 - 3*4  (3 offset).

```
In [181]: x_ext.reshape(6,3).strides
Out[181]: (12, 4)
```

Using `strides=(4,4)` means that the step to next row is just 4 bytes, one element in original.

```
as_strided(x_ext,shape=(8,4),strides=(8,4))
```

produces a 2 item overlap

```
array([[58, 56, 54, 52],
       [54, 52, 50, 48],
       [50, 48, 46, 44],
       [46, 44, 42, 40],
       ....
```

The potentially dangerous part of `as_strided` is that it is possible to create an array that samples memory outside of the original data buffer.  Usually that appears as large random numbers where `None` appears in this example.  It's the same sort of error that you would encounter if C code if you were careless in using array pointers and indexing.

The `as_strided` array is a view (the repeated values are not copied).  So writing to that array could be dangerous.  The `column_stack` with `x` will make a copy, replicating the repeated values as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to contruct an initial matrix with equal columns and then use `np.roll()` to rotate them:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit as ti
import numpy.matlib

x = range(30,60,2)[::-1];
x = np.asarray(x);

def sol1():
    # Your solution, for comparison
    arr = np.empty((0,5), int)

    for i,e in enumerate(x):
        arr2 = np.hstack((x[i], x[i:i+4], np.asarray([None]*5)))[:5]
        arr  = np.vstack((arr,arr2))
    return arr

def sol2():
    # My proposal
    x2 = np.hstack((x, [None]*3))
    mat = np.matlib.repmat(x2, 5, 1)
    for i in range(3):
        mat[i+2, :] = np.roll(mat[i+2, :], -(i+1))
    return mat[:,:-3].T


print(ti.timeit(sol1, number=100))
print(ti.timeit(sol2, number=100))
```

which guives:

```
0.026760146000015084
0.0038611710006080102
```

It uses a for loop but it only iterates over the shorter axis. Also, it should not be hard to adapt this code for other configurations instead of using hardcoded numbers.

Comment: Could you post the outputs of timeit?

Comment: There it is. As you can see it's slower than other answers :/

Comment: It is indeed slower than @Divakar answer by a factor of 2 more or less